# JavaScript message loop that fades in

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck, new to JavaScript.
In HTML, I can get a loop to display successive messages from an array. I am trying to get the messages to fade in rather than suddenly appearing.  I can do both effects separately with the code below but I cannot seem to combine them and make it work.  Appreciate any comment/help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #messaging{ 
            font-size: 35pt; 
        } 
    </style> 
    <script type ="text/javascript" >
        var phrases = ["message1",
            "message2",
            "message3",
            "message4"];
        var msgCycleRate = 3000;
        var text;
        function get( id0 ) {
            return document.getElementById( id0 );
        }
        function cycleMsgs( id1 ) { 
            if ('undefined' === typeof id1){
                id1 = -1;
            } 
            id1 = (id1 + 1)% phrases.length; 
            start(text = get( 'messaging' ).innerHTML = phrases[id1]); //line 37 here
            setTimeout( 'cycleMsgs(' + id1 + ');', msgCycleRate); 
        }
        function doMsgs() { 
           setTimeout( 'cycleMsgs();', 0); 
        }
        var opacity = 0.0;
        var alpha= 0;

        function start(textM) {
            textM.style.filter="alpha(opacity = " + alpha +")";
            textM.style.opacity=opacity;
            setTimeout("fadeIn(textM)",50);
        }

        function fadeIn(textM) {
            opacity= opacity +0.1;
            alpha=parseInt(opacity*100);
            textM.style.opacity=opacity;
            textM.style.filter="alpha(opacity = " + alpha +")";
            if (opacity < 1.0) {
                setTimeout("fadeIn(textM)",50);
            }
        }
        if(window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('load', doMsgs, false); // non-IE
        }
        else { 
            window.attachEvent('onload', doMsgs); // IE 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
   <p id ="messaging">/p>
</body>
```

I run code and get:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'filter' of undefined or null reference, line 37 character 17

What am I not seeing here?  Thanks again.

Comment: Please oh please try jquery for this sort of stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the HTML to the `start` function, not the `messaging` DOM element itself.  If you split up line 37, the problem becomes more clear:

```
get( 'messaging' ).innerHTML = phrases[id1];
text = get( 'messaging' ).innerHTML;
start(text);
```

You can fix this by passing the DOM element to `start` instead:

```
start(get('messaging'));
```

Comment: Perfect, solution is good.  For others looking to this code, you have to reset opacity and alpha variables before loop recalls start(), otherwise fade in will not materialize.